# Tensorflow Canned Estimator problems running with multiple workers on Google cloud ml engine

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am trying to train a model using the canned DNNClassifier estimator on the google cloud ml-engine.

I am able to successfully train the model locally in single and distributed mode. Further I am able to train the model on the cloud with the provided BASIC and BASIC_GPU scale-tier.

I am now trying to pass my own custom config file. When I only specify "masterType: standard" in the config file without mentioning workers, parameter servers, the job runs successfully.

However, whenever I try adding workers, the job fails:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard
  workerType: standard
  workerCount: 4
```

Here is how I run the job (I get the same error without mentioning the staging bucket):

```
SCALE_TIER=CUSTOM
JOB_NAME=chasingdatajob_10252017_13
OUTPUT_PATH=gs://chasingdata/$JOB_NAME
STAGING_BUCKET=gs://chasingdata
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME --staging-bucket "$STAGING_BUCKET" --scale-tier $SCALE_TIER --config $SIMPLE_CONFIG --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH --module-name trainer.task --package-path trainer/ --region $REGION -- ...
```

My job log shows that the job exited with a non-zero status of 1. I see the following error for worker-replica-3:

```
Command '['gsutil', '-q', 'cp', u'gs://chasingdata/chasingdatajob_10252017_13/e476e75c04e89e4a0f2f5f040853ec21974ae0af2289a2563293d29179a81199/trainer-0.1.tar.gz', u'trainer-0.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Ive checked my bucket (gs://chasingdata). I see chasingdatajob_10252017_13 directory created by the engine but there is no trainer-0.1.tar.gz file. Another thing to mention - I am passing "tensorflow==1.4.0rc0" as a PyPi package to the cloud in my setup.py file. I dont think this is the cause of the problem but thought Id mention it anyway.

Is there any reason for this error? Can someone please help me out?

Perhaps I am doing something stupid. I have tried to find an answer (unsuccesfully) for this.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you provide a directory listing: `gsutil ls -l -h gs://chasingdata/chasingdatajob_10252017_13/e476e75c04e89e4a0f2f5f040853ec21974ae0af2289a2563293d29179a81199`

Comment: Sure. Here it is:
`...@angular-vector-181314:~$ gsutil ls -l -h gs://chasingdata/chasingdatajob_10252017_13/e476e75c04e89e4a0f2f5f040853ec21974ae0af2289a2563293d29179a81199`
CommandException: One or more URLs matched no objects.

Comment: And 
`...@angular-vector-181314:~$ gsutil ls -l -h gs://chasingdata/chasingdatajob_10252017_13`
       0 B  2017-10-25T19:25:10Z  gs://chasingdata/chasingdatajob_10252017_13/
 77.55 KiB  2017-10-25T19:25:10Z  gs://chasingdata/chasingdatajob_10252017_13/events.out.tfevents.1508959510.master-5252b8c60b-0-d522f
TOTAL: 2 objects, 79410 bytes (77.55 KiB)

Comment: Can you remove `--staging-bucket` and see if that works?

Comment: @rhaertel80, thanks for your help. I have removed `--staging-bucket` and it still doesnt work. Ive played around with this a little bit and I think the problem is with workerCount. When I change the workerCount to 2, the job runs successfully. But when I set workerCount to 4, it fails with the above error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thats extremely bizarre given the symptoms. Are you willing to post code publicly or send privately to cloudml-feedback@google.com?

Comment: Thank you ill send the code privately to the email

Answer (score 0):

The user code has the logic to delete existing job-dir, which deleted the staged user code package in GCS as well, so that the workers started late were not able to download the package.

We recommend each job has a separate job-dir to avoid similar issue.

Comment: Please note that this is fixed in the [census code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census) as well.